# Hibernate: ObjectNotFoundException when object exists

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have an entity, a `Group`, which has `User` objects inside it. On creation of a `User`, that `User` is added to a `Group`. This is done through an API, so the flow of control is roughly:

1. Complete web form for new user, submit
2. Hibernate creates new user, adds user to group
3. Website requests group and list of users
4. Hibernate loads and returns group
5. Website displays group

Now, when the `User` is first created, they are never present in the `Group` that is returned. On refresh, the `User` appears. On another refresh, the `User` is present, upon a third (?!) refresh, an `ObjectNotFoundException` is thrown for the newly-created `User` object.

I have been battling with this for days, I don't know which parts of the Hibernate actions are relevant, so will eagerly provide more details when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to be clever, I was updating the many-to-many table via SQL and then trying to force Hibernate to reload. I've re-architected the process such that I just let Hibernate take care of the many-to-many table and now everything seems to work fine.